# Mediator pattern - in controller or in application service? [asp.net web api]

Tags: asp.net-web-api, mediator, mediatr

In my next project i want to use mediator pattern (with mediatr lib). In all of the examples i've seen, they inject it directly into controllers.

What i don't like about it is if there is a case where i want to return something other than just `201` with an URL after `POST/PUT/PATCH` requests, for example, a  full version of created/updated resource, i'd have to do all of it in controller itself and that's too much for controller (i want it just to route/dispatch requests).

So, my question is - is it really usual practice to use mediator directly in controllers or is it just for example purposes whereas in production code the mediator would go into some kind of an application service layer?

Answer (score 2):

I've used MediatR for a couple of personal projects and I have found so far that my controllers end up extremely clean and follow a very simple, predictable pattern.

In the configuration of the mediator you tell it which projects contain the request or notification handlers. This *may* be in the same project as your API but is probably a completely separate one. It certainly does not need to be in the controller itself.

The actual mediator is then injected into the controller much like a logger, so you can throw your messages at it. The controller doesn't care what project or service layer handles those messages, that's for the mediator to know, but you can wait in the controller for a response if you are using an `IRequest`. (If you are using an `INotification` then multiple things may take action because of it.)

Anyway, nearly all of my controller methods have ended up following more or less this basic pattern. As you can see, this is returning an object from a GET but the same principal applies to any other verb :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetItemByReference(string reference)
{
    try
    {
        IItem item =
            await this.Mediator.Send(
                new GetItemByReferenceRequest()
                {
                    Reference = reference,
                });

        if (item == null)
        {
            return this.NotFound();
        }

        return this.Ok(item);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        return this.BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

From a solution perspective I have ended up with something akin to this:

- A "UI" project which may be an MVC or API project.
- A project which contains all the mediatr request objects.
- One or more projects which perform request handling.

If I need to then change how a request is handled, I can either create a new handler project and, during the mediator configuration point it at that new project, or update the existing handler project.

I hope this shows how I have found MediatR a very nice way to separate the concerns out in my own experience, and helps you decide whether to use it or not!

Comment: what happens if you want to return updated resource in response to a `PUT` request? or if you want to return complete newly created resource (not just URL) in response to `POST` request?

Comment: Send the request which would create or update the resource and return the created or updated resource from the message handler. Then return it from the controller method.